# Collaborators chat with Google Drive / Realtime API

Tags: javascript, cloud, google-drive-api

I am looking to extend a web application using the new real time API in order to support collaboration (javascript). For that purpose I would also like to include a chat which will be available to users collaborating on same document. After extensive search I cannot find parts of the Drive API that can be used for this. Furthermore none of the open-source examples provided by google implement chat functionality.

> Is there existing services/code that I can use to intergrade
>   chat into my application or I would need to implement it?

As mentioned before, the chat should be available to those collaborating on same document.

p.s I do not require any special features, just a simple chat as the one found in google docs etc.

Comment: If your application is hosted on google app engine, you have access to google's [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview).  As for drive api, I think you are correct - their is no existing implementation of their chat.

Comment: The server side is currently in Node.js therefore cant run on appengine.

Comment: Then socket.io is your option - real time chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I don't know of any out-of-the-box solution to this problem.  Some people have implemented chat in a realtime document by just placing the chat messages in the realtime data model.

This works fine so long as you don't also want to use undo/redo feature.  If you are using undo/redo, then people would end up undoing the chat messages.

We are interested in adding some better support for this eventually, but no promises on anything in the short term.

Comment: I also thought about this approach soon after asking this question. Is it not possible to have two realtime data models open on the same client?(the one that is normally being edited + one for the chat)

Comment: Yes that is possible. That seems like a reasonable workaround to the undo problem.

Comment: You can create a [non-undoable Compound Action](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/undo#preventing_undo) that will be skipped when you try to undo.

Comment: Indeed, that option did not exist when I answered this question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build your own chat system, as Google just killed off XMPP support on the Chat API (which largely kills off the use of the API). The new Hangouts API does not provide access to Chat ( though some additional methods may come in handy: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/ for the dev API).

You are therefore left to your own devices. Fear not, however, writing a chat system is pretty easy. I am about to release a (mostly free) service to do so, so if you want to not have to write the code for it, I can keep you posted.

If, however, you'd prefer to build the code for it, you will most likely want to look into either socket.io or [postal.js](http://postaljs.com). both provide the same thing: a pub/sub model. From there, you will need to implement a choice of either:

- Long polling: supported by all browsers but a bit clunky
- Websockets: not supported by IE8 and below

This will serve as your data transfer.

Two other possible options are paid services: you can retrofit [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) to do what you want to do (this, however, will seem clunky). You can also retrofit the [Meteord](http://meteorserver.org/installation/) daemon, which does what you want natively, but has an outdated JS library.

The keyword of all this is pub/sub, though.

Comment: I have found this library it looks like it would come handy if I take the websocket route: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/

Comment: @Giannis: this only solves your client-side debacle. You'll still have to implement both polling and WS server-side. Personally, I tend to stick to long polling for this reason, and will most likely only switch back to websockets once IE8 drops to below 5% usage.